# Impose a condition on set of polynomials $P=\{f_i|i\geq 1\}$ such that the set is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I think the condition should be that the polynomials cannot be of equal degree if they are not of the same index, i.e. if $i\neq j, deg(f_i)\neq deg(g_i)$. Clearly if they are not of the same degee, the only coefficients $\{a_1,...a_n$} such that $a_1f_1+...+a_nf_n$ are $a_n=0, \forall n$But how do I show that this is sufficient? ie how to show the set is indeed linearly independent?

Comment: Your condition is sufficient, but not necessary.  I doubt that there's a simple necessary and sufficient condition that isn't essentially a restatement of the definition of linear independence.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I see it is just sufficient and not a necessary condition, so edited my question

Answer (score 0):

In the vector space of polynomials of degree${}\leq n$ which is of dimension $n+1$ the  set $f_j(x) = x^n + x^j$ for  $0\le j< n,\ f_n=x^n$ is a basis with all elements of degree $n$.

Comment: @Robert Israel. There are n+1. Please count again. Perhaps you did not notice $f_n(x)$ which has a different definition.